# Integration problem difficult to solve

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this differential equation by reduction of order : 
$$xy''-(x+n)y'+ny=0$$given that one of the two solutions is :
$$y_1=e^x$$
While solving the problem , I got the second solution 
$$y_2=e^x \int x^n e^{-x}dx$$
I could not solve this integration .

Comment: Downvote because that surely wasn't the original question.

Comment: I am sorry for that , I thought it is clear . I edited the post .

Comment: Say the integral is $I_n$. Do it first for $n=1,2,3$. Integrate by parts; for $n=2$ integrate by parts twice, three times for $n=3$, etc. You should notice a pattern; guess what $I_n$ is in general. Prove the guess is correct by induction. (For the induction step: An integration by parts gives you $I_{n+1}$ in terms of $I_n$.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(x+n)$ to have $e^x$ as a solution ?

Comment: @zwim. I think that you made a good point !

Comment: @MCS : $y_1=e^x$ is not solution of $xy''-(x-n)y'+ny=0$.  Why don't you never bring back your solution into the ODE to check if it is correct ?That is not the first time that you make a mistake of this kind in your questions.

Comment: I am sorry this is a typo . I edited the post... 
My problem was not in solving the DE or checking whether it is a solution , my problem was in the integration how to solve it .. I just wrote the DE because when I wrote the integration only , someone downvoted me because that was not the original question.

Comment: I am sorry I will revise any posts before I post them to avoid typos in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), you will notice that 
$$\int x^n e^{-x}\,dx=-\Gamma (n+1,x)$$ the famous incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiating $x^n$ $n+1$ times gives you $0$. Integrating $e^{-x}$ $n+1$ times gives you $(-1)^{n+1}e^{-x}$.